# Minimum storage duration Google Cloud Storage buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Google Cloud Platform has minimum storage duration for various bucket types like Nearline, Coldline. In the minimum duration period for Nearline and Coldline buckets can objects be modified or should just be read from the bucket or should it not be read or write within the minimum storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify (overwrite) or delete objects of Nearline or Coldline storage class, it just comes with a price, see details on early deletion here:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#early-deletion

> Early deletion charges apply when you overwrite existing objects, since the original object is replaced by a new one.