# Minimum storage duration for "Regional" or "Multi-Regional" GCS buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Google cloud storage documentation (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) suggests that there is "minimum storage duration" for Nearline (30days) and Coldline (90 days) storage but there is no description about regional and multi-regional storage.

Does it mean that there is absolutely no minimum storage duration? Is the unit by microsecond, second, minute, hour, or a day?

For example, (unrealistically) suppose that I created a google cloud storage bucket, and copied 10 petabyte of the data to the bucket, and removed each piece of data 1 minute after (or moved the data to another bucket I don't have to pay), then, is the cost of regional storage will be

$.02 (per GB per month) * 10,000,000 (GB) * 1/30/24/60 (months) = $4.62 ?

If the "unit" of GCS bucket usage time is an hour rather than a minute, then the cost will be $278. If it is 12 hours, the cost will be $3333, so there are huge differences in such an extreme case.

I want to create a "temporary bucket" that holds petabyte-scale data in a short period of time, and just wanted to know what the budget should be. The previous question ([Minimum storage duration Google Cloud Storage buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525249/minimum-storage-duration-google-cloud-storage-buckets)) did not help in answering to my question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no minimum storage duration for regional or multi-regional buckets, but keep in mind that you will still have to pay [operations costs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) to upload.  At the time of this writing, that would be $0.05 per 10,000 files uploaded.

I believe the granularity of billing is seconds, so your initial calculation $4.62 would be correct.  But note depending on the average size of your files, uploading a petabyte is likely to be more expensive than that; if you have a petabyte of files that are 100MB in size, the operations cost for the uploads would be ~$50.